# Informatica About Source Qualifier joining and multiple targets in one mapping

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Hello dear stackoverflow wizards,

Attached is a screenshot of the mapping in question. The Source Tables come from the same database. I tried to join the tables using a single Source Qualifier transformation. I also put all three targets in one mapping.

Would this work? If not, is it possible to use the Source Qualifier to join in a different case and is it possible to have multiple targets in one mapping at all?

My instructor gave me 0 points, I should have used a joiner and three seperate mappings (was not instructed to and not taught about joiners prior. Very basic course).

Thank you very much!

Best wishes, Cam [The Mapping in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWaEW.png)

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn’t work as Data Integrity may fail. There are Foreign keys between these tables. First you need to upload data into Households table, then to Customers and after that to Orders.
It’s good to create three separate mappings and connect them sequentially in Workflow Manager. You can also create three separate data loads in one mapping, but you need to define *Target Load Group Order* (Click Mappings in Toolbar) to specify in which order Integration Service (IS) should load them. And, actually, you don't need to join anything.
I don’t see any issues using Source Qualifier to join tables, even filtering or ordering data there, but usually good practice is to use Joiners after SQ (or SQ >> FILTER >> JOINER). With Joiner you can join only two sources at a time.
Here is what Informatica says about Joiner Transformation:
*Use the Joiner transformation to join source data from two related heterogeneous sources residing in different locations or file systems. You can also join data from the same source.*
And about Source Qualifier:
*Join data originating from the same source database. You can join two or more tables with primary key-foreign key relationships by linking the sources to one Source Qualifier transformation.*
*Joining Source Data

Use one Source Qualifier transformation to join data from multiple relational tables. These tables must be accessible from the same instance or database server. When a mapping uses related relational sources, you can join both sources in one Source Qualifier transformation. During the session, the source database performs the join before passing data to the Integration Service. This can increase performance when source tables are indexed. Tip: Use the Joiner transformation for heterogeneous sources and to join flat files.*

Comment: Hey Ikacho, thank you very much for you in depth answer! Could you please elaborate on the problem with the foreign keys? Is it not possible to use the SQ to join because of the foreign keys or would the foreign keys just beco e a problem because of the number of targets? We just learned about the Workflow Manager after this exercise, so I understand that the table without foreign keys has to  the "filled" first and so on as to not cause issues. What do you mean with me not needing any joiners at all? As thr targets have multiple attributes from multiple sources joiners/SQ would be needed no?

Comment: Hey @JamesCam. Issue can be on database side. When you have Foreign Keys you need to have predefined master record, like when posting a record in Customers table Household_Id value should exist in Household table. Otherwise it fails on DB side and it fails your Informatica IS.
You can use Lookups instead of Joiners or Source Qualifiers (for joining tables), but if you are in learning process use Joiners as your instructor expecting. Cheers